# In the complex plane, show that the points $-5+4i$, $1+i$, and $-1-3i$ are vertices of a right triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

The question reads:

> The points $u = -5 + 4i$, $v = 1 + i$ and $w = -1 - 3i$ form the vertices of a scalene triangle on the Argand plane. Prove the triangle is right angled and calculate the triangle's area on the Argand plane in square units.

Firstly, I tried to figure out what the length of side formed by $u$ ($-5+4i$) and $v$ ($1+i$), called $L_1$. I calculated the modulus of each of these but was unable to find the length of that side of the triangle. The solutions state that you find this length by subtracting $u$ from $v$, ($v-u$), and then finding the modulus of this, which is $\sqrt{45}$.

> Why exactly is this the correct method to find the length of $L_1$? Why do we go $u-v$ - aren't $u$ and $v$ both lines going from the center, not sides of the triangle? And How can the modulus of $u-v$ be the length of $L_1$?

Comment: Think of the modulus of $u-v$ as the familiar distance formula between the two points $(-5, 4)$ and $(1, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This should make it clear why they are considering $u-v$ to find the length of the side.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts what's the formula for the familiar distance? I searched online and it says it is sqrt (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2, isn't that different from what we are doing here (as they are adding)?

Comment: Yes, that is the distance formula. This will align exactly with the modulus of u-v.

Comment: But shouldn't the formula be  (x2-x1)^2 - (y2-y1)^2? instead? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way. Subtracting two points in the complex plane tells you the "difference" between them, in terms of magnitude and direction.

Here, point $a$ is $v - u$, calculated by $(2+2i)-(1+3i)=(1-i)$.

[image]

As you can see, the distance between point $a$ and the origin is the same as the distance between $a$ and $b$. In fact, you can think of this as the same as vector subtraction.

The modulus of $u$ or $v$ would just give the distance between it and the origin, which isn't helpful. To find the distance between $u$ and $v$, you'd have to find the modulus of their difference, or the modulus of point $a$.

Basically, the distance between $u$ and $v$ is the distance formula applied to their difference, or point $a$.

$$\sqrt{(v_x-u_x)^2+(v_y-u_y)^2}$$
$$\sqrt{(a_x)^2+(a_y)^2}$$
above, point u is $(u_x+u_yi)$, point v is $(v_x+v_yi)$, and point a is $(a_x+a_yi)$

$$\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(2-3)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$

Although finding the length of a segment might not be the best way to solve the problem, I hope this clarifies your question.

Side note:
I know it gets confusng to think of points on the complex plane as sums of real and imaginary numbers, so, at least for basic applications, it helps to view complex numbers as vectors on the x/y plane. (keep in mind that 2d vectors and complex numbers are not the same, especially with multiplication)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the lengths?

$u-v = -6+3i\\
w-v = -2-4i$

As $(w-v) = \frac 23i (u-v)$

$\arg (w-v) - \arg (u-v) = \arg (\frac 23i)$

Answer (score 1):

I guess this requires you to go to look into the basics of complex numbers. You are confusing them with vectors. And if you want to approach vectorially, you may think of the real part as a unit vector $i$ along $X$-axis (real axis of Argand plane) and imaginary part as one along $Y$ axis, $j$.

*(i)* No, $u=-5+4i$ is not a line from the centre. It is a point on the Argand plane, which can be reached by travelling 5 units along the negative real axis and then 4 units along the positive imaginary axis. This thought process is applicable for vectors.

*(ii)* $u-v$ gives you another complex number (Closure Property) , $-6+3i$ ,represented by two numbers, $-6$ and $3$ . Neither of them represents the length.
The modulus of a complex number - here $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}$ - represents its distance from the origin. When you evaluate $u-v$ , the so thought vector from $v$ to $u$,can be translated now from $0$ to  $u-v$. During translation,its length remains same. And now its modulus gives the length.

If this provokes you so as to why we use complex algebra- a seemingly tougher system as compared to vectors - for one, they are lot more flexible, and can be represented by a single entity,as opposed to two. You will get to know more as you delve deeper into it.